# Where do I add semi-colons in JS to prevent minification errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've had problems before when merging lots of JS code and running through a minification program where due to the absence of semi-colons it resulted in parsing errors.

I always use braces, e.g.:

```
if() {

} else {

}
```

... so it wasn't due to that. I also always use semi-colons in the obvious places, e.g.:

```
var a = "foo";
var b = "bar";
```

My fix required lots of semi-colons after braces, like below, and since this I have became obsessed with doing this for every piece of JS I write:

```
function() {

    if() {

        for() {

        };

    };

};
```

...but I think that's too much.

So where do I need to put a semi-colon to guarantee I don't get these errors when compressing?

I particularly get a problem if I dump a few jQuery scripts (uncompressed) in a file and then compress them.

Comment: Have you tried JSLint - JS code quality tool like this http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php

Comment: Run a linter on your JavaScript (like JSHint or JSLint). It should complain about missing semicolons and extraneous semicolons.

Comment: That's bizarre; semicolons aren't required after braces. You should use semicolons after statements. The only weird edge case is inside a `for` statement where semicolons are used to separate the three "chunks", there cannot be one after the third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to always use semicolons in javascript. This is a common example of when javascript breaks without semicolons:

```
var my_fn = function () {
    //...
}

(function () {
    //...
})();
```

This would be interpreted as:

```
var my_fn = function () {
    //...
} (function () {
    //...
})();
```

i.e. the first function will be called with the second as a parameter (expecting it to return a function to call again).

I recommend you to use http://www.jslint.com/ to review your code.

Answer (score 1):

[StandardJS](https://github.com/standard/standard/blob/caa357395b48bc5e1cced3c85a5eb47bbf4aeac8/RULES.md#helpful-reading) doesn’t recommend to use semicolons :

> “All popular code minifiers in use today use AST-based minification,
> so they can handle semicolon-less JavaScript with no issues (since
> semicolons are not required in JavaScript).”

From [RULES.md#helpful-reading](https://github.com/standard/standard/blob/caa357395b48bc5e1cced3c85a5eb47bbf4aeac8/RULES.md#helpful-reading)